Not being able to access SharePoint List with Python
I'm attempting to automate some queries using Python, but I'm encountering difficulties connecting to and extracting data from a SharePoint List (which is what my organization uses). The simplest method I've found so far is using the "win32com.client" module from the "pywin32" package.
I'm encountering this error block when I try to execute the code:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception.', (0, 'Microsoft Access Database Engine', "The Microsoft Access Database Engine could not find the object '{LIST_ID}'. Please verify that the object exists and that you have entered the name and path correctly. If '{LIST_ID}' is not a local object, check the network connection or contact the server administrator.", None, 5003011, -2147217865), None)
This is what my code looks like:
import win32com.client

# Define SharePoint site URL and list name
    site_url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/path/"
    list_name = "{LIST_ID}"

    # Create connection string
    conn_str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" \
                "WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" \
                "DATABASE={0};LIST={1};".format(site_url, list_name)

    # Create ADODB connection
    conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
    conn.Open(conn_str)

    # Execute SQL query
    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM [{}];".format(list_name)
    rs = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Recordset')
    rs.Open(sql_query, conn)

    # Get all records at once
    records = rs.GetRows()

    # Get field names
    fields = [field.Name for field in rs.Fields]

    # Close connections
    rs.Close()
    conn.Close()

When I try to run the code on my work computer, it works (yes, without authentication), but not on my home computer (it raises the same exception).
It started to bother me when I tried to run two queries (from different lists) in sequence - which is really necessary for me - and it raised the same exception. (I've tried running it with async, and it still had the same problem.)

Did you mean to use an actual "list id" instead of {LIST ID}?

Yes, actually "{LIST-ID}" in my code is replaced by the value of the list I want to access.

Where? It seems it isn't replaced, otherwise the error message would not mention {LIST ID}.

Sorry, I also replaced it in the error message to avoid putting the real value of the list... Is there a correct way to indicate this?
